# Am i able to use user input as the colour in colorama module?

Tags: python, colorama

i am trying to write a program using the colorama module that prints a user's input message in a chosen colour. Is there any way to do this other than using a bunch of If statements. Here is my code at the moment:

```
From Colorama Import Fore, Init 
msg = input("Enter Message here")
color = input("Enter colour (list of all color options)")
color = color.upper()
Print(Fore.color + msg)
```

Right now my code gives me an error in the last line due to color not being a recognised color for the Fore. keyword but i was hoping it would use the user input of the colour.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your code probably gives you an error because `message` is undefined. Use `msg` instead and see if that works.

Comment: that was an accident typing it on here in my code i used msg in both lines.

Comment: What do you get when you print `type(Fore.color)`?

Comment: AttributeEror: 'AnsiFore' object has no attribute 'color'

Comment: Well, there you go then. `Fore` does not have an attribute named `color`. Did you mean to do this instead maybe `print(color + msg)`?

Comment: No because i want to print the text in the colour using the Fore object e.g. Fore.GREEN would print the text in green. If the user inputs green and this is saved as color is there no way the program would recognise this and print the text in green with Fore.color.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly now, this is what you would like to do:

```
From Colorama Import Fore, Init 

msg = input("Enter Message here")
color = input("Enter colour (list of all color options)")
color = color.upper()
Print(getattr(Fore, color) + msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

`color` variable is not the same as `.color` property of `Fore`

ie:

- Setting `color` means you have a variable with some string
- Calling `Fore.color` or getting the attribute just access the property value for the `Fore` class

You should get the list of color options from Colorama as string, then just use the `color` variable